# Redis CLI - access keys from Laravel Cache connection

Tags: laravel, redis

I can connect to my Redis instance via the cli with the following code:

```
redis-cli -p 6999 -a password
```

port and password changed for security purposes.

And this opens up a redis REPL, and I can see all the keys on my Redis instance via `keys *`.

However, it doesn't actually show me ALL of my keys. I use Laravel Cache with the redis driver (the `Cache::remember` interface), and inside of Laravel I can list all the keys via `$keys = Redis::connection('cache')->keys('*');` -- and that shows me a very different list from what I see in the repl.

Any key that I set in Laravel through the default connection shows in the cli repl, but not any key set through the cache.

Is there any way to see the keys set through `::connection('cache')` in the cli repl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you have multiple Redis databases in use.

You can find out which database your cache is stored in by looking at `config/database.php`

```
   /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix'  => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url'      => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url'      => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],
    ],
```

To switch between databases within `redic-cli` you can run the following command within the CLI:

`SELECT 1`

IF you haven't explicitly updated your `.env` file with settings for the cache database, then your cache will be in DB 1

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, it did something weird: I'm on shared hosting, but I just share it with other servers that I also own, and I have redis set up for each website that's on that single shared server, each one of my websites has its own Redis port (eg the one above uses, say, 3000, and another uses 3001, and another 3002)

Comment: And so I signed in to the cli for the port 3000 one, and I can see values from 3001 and 3002 apparently, when i do `keys *`. Is that... normal?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not the best to ask about the internal working of Redis. However, if you have multiple instances of Redis running, they should not be sharing databases!